# "Content is not allowed in prolog" while unmarshaling Json Object

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jackson

I am trying to unmarshall the Json Object which I get back from Restful Service response. But it's throwing an exception while doing unmarshalling?

**MyClass.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyClass
{
  @XmlElement(name="id")
  private String id;

  @XmlElement(name="f-name")
  private String fname;


  @XmlElement(name="l-name")
  private String lname;

 // getters and setters for these

}
```

unmarshal method

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
Unmarshaller unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();  
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/service-location");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept",  "application/json");
connection.connect();
MyClass myclass=(MyClass)unMarshaller.unmarshal(connection.getInputStream());
```

And when I tried using some browser client I am getting proper response like below.

```
[
    {
        "fname": "JOHN",
        "lname": "Doe",
        "id": "abc123"          
    }
]
```

But I am trying to do Unmarshall in my Client Code it's throwing `SAXParserException`

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;  lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

I not sure what I am doing wrong. Is this way to do unmarshall the JSON object or is there any other way to do it?

***UPDATE : SOLUTION***

I fixed this by implementing `Jackson's ObjectMapper` rather than conventional `UnMarshaller` of `JAXB`. Here is my Code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, MYClass.class);
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
list = mapper.readValue(jsonString, type); // JsonString is my response converted into String of json data.
```

Comment: You have specified your JSON as an array, try without [ and ]

Comment: I tried with Valid JSON as a test case. It still throwing this error.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis.. I test for BOM's but found nothing. So, it's all good from that perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Vanilla JAXB**

You are currently using JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding) to process the JSON.  It is expecting XML so you are getting an error.

**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**

If you are using MOXy as your JAXB provider there is a property you can set to put it in JSON mode (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html).

**Jackson**

If you are intending to use Jackson then you need to use their runtime APIs.

- http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations

Comment: Yes. I tried your some of the examples from your blog. They work pretty well. But we are tied to jackson so Can't change the version now.And more over we are running on Jboss so not sure anything messed up there

Comment: @SRy - Understandable.  Jackson can interpret some of the JAXB metadata, but they have their own runtime API: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to right direction. I fixed it by jackson's native objectMapper. By the way great work on EclipseLink Moxy JaxB implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the unmarshaller to be JSON, otherwise it'll default to XML parsing.

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
```

Or use a JSON parser, such as Google GSON, to do the unmarshalling.